# time elapsed in html 5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an html5 application in which i want to show time elapsed from start of the application and should stop when i want it to. how to do it using java script. please give some example or references.

Comment: @Daniel yes it should start on clicking a button and stop when i want to....

Answer (score 1):

There are many pre-made Javascript timers such as this one, http://bornagainprogrammer.net/2010/08/19/a-simple-stop-watch-timer-using-jquery/, which you can find online.

After you build one or find one, attach it to run `.ready()`, then allow the user to stop it by pressing a button...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Start timer
});
```

Then to end the timer

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
  // End timer
});
```

<sub>Note, the two examples above use [jQuery](http://jquery.com).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Charlies answer that requires a full featured framework for doing a simple task, and depending on your requirements - a pure and simple timeout function would do the trick much easier and in lighter weight. [See this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/).

The link explains how to create the most simple timer in javascript, but will also teach about the inaccuracy of this method - and also provide you with an example of how to create a very accurate timer using the Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example in javascript that creating a timer:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
myTimer();
setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
}

var d=new Date();

function myTimer()
{
var newd = new Date();
var diff = newd.getTime() - d.getTime();
diff = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
document.getElementById("Clock").innerHTML=diff ;
}
</script>
```